# ¿Cómo puedo adaptar este código a una función y un procedimiento?

Tags: c++, funciones, dev-c++

Me pidieron que realizara un programa que mediante un procedimiento, le solicitara al usuario las notas definitivas y el sexo de 25 estudiantes que cursaron una materia y al mismo tiempo que va leyendo las notas debe almacenarlas en forma separadas las de los varones y de las hembras. Y posterior a ello que calcule, mediante funciones diferentes, el promedio general de la sección, el promedio obtenido por los varones, el promedio obtenido por las hembras.

Sólo llevo esto y aun no le he aplicado las funciones ni los procedimientos como les mencione anteriormente:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  int contador = 0;
  int hombres = 0;
  int mujeres = 0;
  int acumulador = 0;
  int notas = 0;
  char sexo;
  float Promedio = 0;

  do
  {
    cout << "Indique la nota del estudiante:  ";
    cin >> notas;
    cout << "Indique el sexo del estudiante:  ";
    cin >> sexo;

    if (sexo == 'F') {
      acumulador = acumulador + notas;
      mujeres = mujeres + 1;
    }

    cout << endl;

    if (sexo == 'M') {
      acumulador = acumulador + notas;
      hombres = hombres + 1;
    }

    contador++;
    acumulador = acumulador + notas;
  }
  while (contador < 25);

  cout << endl;
  cout << endl;

  cout << "Notas totales de la seccion " << endl;

  cout << contador;
  cout << endl;
  cout << endl;

  cout << "Mujeres totales de la seccion " << endl;

  cout << mujeres;
  cout << endl;
  cout << endl;

  cout << "Hombres totales de la seccion " << endl;

  cout << hombres;
  cout << endl;
  cout << endl;

  cout << "Promedio de la seccion en base a las notas ingresadas" << endl;
  Promedio = acumulador / 25;
  cout << endl;
  cout << Promedio << endl << endl;

  cout << "Promedio de las hembras en base a las notas ingresadas" << endl;
  Promedio = acumulador / mujeres;
  cout << endl;
  cout << Promedio << endl << endl;

  cout << "Promedio de los varones en base a las notas ingresadas" << endl;
  Promedio = acumulador / hombres;
  cout << endl;
  cout << Promedio << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Espero que alguien me pueda ayudar, y darme una idea de como puedo hacerlo.

Comment: No entiendo la pregunta, el programa hace exactamente lo que dices que debe hacer. ¿Cuál es la duda?

Comment: Pero ahí no reflejo ninguna función bro, y me están pidiendo que los promedios los calcule mediante funciones diferentes, esa es mi pregunta, como hago para hacer una función con esos datos que me piden?

Comment: Bro yo puedo hacer otra pregunta aparte?, ya que tengo una duda distinta a esta

Answer (score 0):

Te presento una posible solución, para recoger los 25 datos tanto notas como el sexo de los alumnos, hace falta definir dos arrays de este tamaño, posteriormente dentro del mismo bucle puedes ir realizando los cálculos para una vez finalizo el bucle mostrarlos y calcular la media.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define NUM_ALUMNOS 5

//Definimos la función promedio: tipo_retorno nombre_funcion(parametro float, parametro numero)
float promedio(float notas, int num){
    return notas / num;
}

//Definimos un procedimiento que imprime el promedio
void imprimir (float promedio, char sexo){
    if (sexo == 'M'){
        cout << "Promedio notas masculinas " << promedio << "\n";
    }
    else {
        cout << "Promedio notas femeninas " << promedio << "\n";
    }
}

int main(){
    
    int hombres = 0, mujeres = 0, contador = 0, total = 0;
    float ac_nota_m = 0, ac_nota_f = 0;
    float nota_num;
    char sexo;
    
    
    for (contador = 0;contador < NUM_ALUMNOS;contador++){
        cout << "Introduce nota: ";
        cin >> nota_num;
        cout;
        
        cout << "Introduce sexo [M,F]: ";
        cin >> sexo;
        cout;
        
        if (sexo == 'M'){
            hombres = hombres + 1;
            ac_nota_m = ac_nota_m + float(nota_num);
        }
        else{
            if (sexo == 'F'){
                mujeres = mujeres + 1;
                ac_nota_f = ac_nota_f + float(nota_num);
            }
        }
        total = total + 1;
        
    }
    
    //Resultados
    cout << "Resultados \n";
    cout << "Datos totales: " << total << " notas\n";
    cout << "Notas masculinas " << hombres << "\n";
    if (hombres > 0){
        //Utilizamos la función promedio definida anteriormente
        imprimir(promedio(ac_nota_m,hombres),'M');
    }
    else{
        cout << "Sin notas masculinas \n";
    }
    
    cout << "Notas femeninas " << mujeres << "\n";
    
    if (mujeres > 0){
        //Utilizamos la función promedio definida anteriormente
        imprimir(promedio(ac_nota_f,mujeres),'F');
    }
    else{
        cout << "Sin notas femeninas \n";
    }
    
    return 0;
    
}
```

Tienes que tener en cuenta aspectos como si no hay hombres (M) o mujeres (F) en los datos, no podrás hacer la media al no poder dividir por 0, de ahí la comprobación final. Añado la definición de la [función](https://www2.eii.uva.es/fund_inf/cpp/temas/8_funciones/funciones.html) promedio y el procedimiento imprimir.

Comment: Yo ahí no veo ni una sola función

Comment: Eso le indico al final, que no veo la necesidad de definir una función en este caso.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta bro, pero yo ya lo hice con arrays y me dijeron que no hacia falta hacer eso, ya que solo están pidiendo hacer una función con esos datos que me dieron.....Realmente esa es mi pregunta, como hago una función usando esos datos que me están solicitando?

Comment: Añado a la respuesta la función promedio, para calcular la nota media de hombres y nota media de mujeres.

Comment: No me pudiera dar un ejemplo para tener mas claro lo que usted dice, así lo aplico a ver que tal??

Comment: En la respuesta en el código he añadido la función promedio, con la suma de la notas calculadas por sexo y el número de mujeres o hombres retorna la media aritmética.

Comment: Pero a que parte del algoritmo de refieres?, ya que no entiendo y disculpe

Comment: Antes de la función main, defino la funcion promedio, float promedio(float,int) para posteriormente en la parte de resultados utilizarla con dos parámetros, las suma de las notas por sexo y el total de mujeres o hombres.

Comment: Entiendo broo, pero como haría para adaptar en tal caso tu código a lo que me piden quitando las arrays?, ya que también estoy un poco confundido con eso

Comment: Modifico el código de la respuesta para no incluir arrays.

Comment: Listo bro, ya la adapte a mi forma y funciona, de verdad muchísimas gracias!!  pero otra preguntica, ahora como hago para hacer el procedimiento?, ya que debería de ir un void no?, como se haría en ese caso?

Comment: El procedimiento podrías hacerlo haciendo un void imprimir(float media) { cout << ....}  y cada vez que imprimes algo por pantalla utilizarlo.

Comment: Pero como declaro esto, seria antes de la función o luego?,"void imprimir(float media) { cout << ....}", me gustaría que si es tan amable lo aplique en el código que usted me envió para notar la diferencia

Comment: Igual que la función promedio, pero void imprimir (float dato) {cout<<...} puedes hacerlo después de la función promedio.

Comment: Pero que datos pongo después del imprimir?, me refiero adentro del paréntesis , y también que debo colocar adentro del cout?

Comment: Llegados a este punto creo que lo mejor sería una lectura a algo como https://www.uv.es/sto/cursos/c++/curso95.pdf

Comment: Bro allí no salen ejemplos gráficos de procedimientos:(, pero esta muy buena la info, ya leí sobre eso

Comment: Añado el procedimiento imprimir para imprimir la línea de promedio, recibe dos parámetros, el dato y el sexo para imprimir según el sexo.

Comment: Bro yo puedo hacer otra pregunta aparte?, ya que tengo una duda distinta a esta

Comment: No lo has conseguido?

Answer (score 0):

En C++ las funciones se definen así:

```
tipo_de_retorno nombre_de_la_función(parametro(s) ...);
```

Parece que tú quieres una función que calcule promedios de una colección de valores:

```
float calcular_el_promedio_de(colección_de_valores);
```

El promedio se calcula sumando todos los valores y dividiendo por la cantidad de valores:

```
float calcular_el_promedio_de(colección_de_valores)
{
    return
        std::accumulate(std::begin(colección_de_valores), std::end(colección_de_valores), .0f) /
        colección_de_valores.size();
}
```

Te muestro un ejemplo con código funcional:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>

float calcular_el_promedio_de(const std::vector<int> &valores)
{
    return
        std::accumulate(std::begin(valores), std::end(valores), .0f) /
        valores.size();
}

int main()
{
    std::vector valores = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 100 };

    std::cout << "El promedio de: ";
    for (const auto &v : valores)
        std::cout << v << ' ';
    std::cout << "es:\n" << calcular_el_promedio_de(valores);

    return 0;
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZDdbsIwDIWvyVMcMWkUEVjL2F9buNtbTEJZ6qJKaYKSlIshXn1dChTYpEVK5NjHn60jt9upVEJv2vau0lI1BSGvjPOWRL1i15xuarKVvE3tSHpjV4yVyggPKZRslLBrUuutNTUVlVkXFEmjnYfzRZqeOvJK@xXud0IZS27M9gzhWPKN1cewO0e9kLKpA9NTdPx/0qbSUd/ITyLSxU1qFpdjPFww58LMVV8UjTN2YCxMRy0Cp5s8uNmrF2OJPRKOOccjx4LjieOZ44XjleONI4nDDfUkCJKgSBZdLsYhY2eeNI1HnmP4rtBbgYJSDDM2KMOksymi8SYYgRQXMwa/CbvuGWGU/SWTSz/0sAv/871HdludzEUcDGjbb1kqsXHtNBCXcjKZix8)</kbd>.

Comment: Ya la función la tengo lista bro, ahora estoy confundido es en los procedimientos usando el void...

Comment: Yo también estoy confundido @JorgeMiguel , `void` no se puede usar pues no es instanciable. Y usas funciones y procedimientos indistintamente, no se qué quieres decir con cada uno de esos términos.